# WPF C# DataGridComboBoxColumn не могу правильно привязать данные

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-datagrid

ребята, я новичок в WPF и у меня проблема с DataGridComboBoxColumn.
У меня есть ObservableCollection
Мне нужно при выборе показывать name в DataGridComboBoxColumn и чтобы selectedValue = id.

MarkWithID.cs

```
using System;

public class MarkWithID
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public MarkWithID()
    {
        id = 0;
        name = "undefinded";
    }
    public MarkWithID(int id, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    ~MarkWithID() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Out..");
    }
}
```

PageData.xaml code

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Марка" Width="100" x:Name="DGCMark"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding marks}"
                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding id}"
                    SelectedValuePath="id" 
                    DisplayMemberPath="name">
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Page.xaml.cs

```
public PageDetailData()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Detail objsDetail = new Detail();
    Machina objsCars = new Machina();
    objsDetail.ReadDataFromFile();
    objsCars.ReadDataFromFile();

    List<DetailFields> list = objsDetail.GetData();
    DetailDataGrid.ItemsSource = list;

    ObservableCollection<MarkWithID> marks = objsCars.GetDataMark();
    DGCMark.ItemsSource = marks;
}
```

Comment: Запомните одно очень простое правило, на нем основан весь механизм привязок: Привязка возможна **только к публичным свойствам**. Также `DetailDataGrid.ItemsSource` у вас быть не должно, ибо это также делается через привязки `<DataGrid ItemsSource = "{Binding List}">`, где `List` - это публичное свойство, которое находится в классе, который задан как `DataContext` окну/объекту (обычно задают один раз `DataContext` окну при старте приложения, этого достаточно). В хорошем проекте, у вас не должно быть вообще `x:Name` в XAML (лишь если нужны для самого XAML, но не C#!)..

Comment: Как это решает вопрос с DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Comment: Для решения каких-либо задач, для начала надо хотя бы заставить работать то, что имеется. А для этого надо понимать то, что вы сделали не так, выше я про ваши ошибки и сказал. Также этот участок кода странный `DGCMark.ItemsSource = marks;`, ибо это должно быть свойством внутри `DetailFields`, а не как отдельная коллекция со своими, не связанными с основными, данными.